# Call Web-API from Telerik Appbuilder Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, telerik

I have two projects, one is a MVC API project thats connected to my Azure doucument DB. The other one is a Telerik Appbuilder project (They are included in the same solution).

I am building a login system. With my MVC project I can register and login without any problems. The tricky part is to login with my Telerik Appbuilder project. I want to manipulate the controllers in the MVC project either via Knockout or Ajax or the two together.

So to the code..

This is my index.html (The Telerik-App) that uses knockout as you can see.

```
    <script src="kendo/js/jquery.js"></script>
<!--<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="kendo/js/knockout-3.2.0.debug.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>-->
<script src="kendo/js/knockout-kendo.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/app.js"></script>

        <form data-bind="submit: register" method="POST">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Email" data-bind="value: registerEmail" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" data-bind="value: registerPassword" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" data-bind="value: registerPassword2" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The Data-bindings points to app.js (also in Telerik-app), app.js looks like this...

```
function ViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.registerEmail = ko.observable();
self.registerPassword = ko.observable();
self.registerPassword2 = ko.observable();

function showError(jqXHR) {
    self.result(jqXHR.status + ': ' + jqXHR.statusText);
}

self.register = function () {
    self.result('');

    var data = {
        Email: self.registerEmail(),
        Password: self.registerPassword(),
        ConfirmPassword: self.registerPassword2()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:15746/api/Account/Register',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.result("Done!");
    }).fail(showError);
}
```

}

var app = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(app);

So. In the Ajax call you can se that it points to my AccountController method Register (This method works if i run the MVC project solo).

If I run the app and open up debug mode i can see that what I've written in the textboxes are shown in the debug, but it doesn't get POSTed to my database.

I'm doing something wrong, I don't fully understand how knockout works. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `self.result` is not defined in your viewmodel which causes `register` to abort. If it's not a typo here, fix it in your code. Apart from this, your code should work.

Comment: `self.result` should be declared before you use it '